# How to avoid scenario where Process2 keeps waiting for Process1 to release the named_mutex

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, mutex, boost-interprocess

I have several processes but only one should be running at the time. This means that let's say the **Process1** is running and if the **Process2** get launched, then **Process2** should wait until **Process1** is complete. I am considering the **boost named_mutex** for this with code like below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/named_mutex.hpp>

using namespace boost::interprocess;

int main()
{
    named_mutex mutex(open_or_create, "some_name");

    try
    {
        mutex.lock();

        // Do work

        mutex.unlock();
    }
    catch (const std::exception& ex)
    {
        mutex.unlock();
        std::cout << ex.what();
    }
}
```

Questions:
1. I would like to make sure that there is no situation where **Process2** get starved of acquiring the lock if **Process1** encounters any handled/unhandled exception?
2. Is there any c# like finally mechanism in c++ that could be helpful in this use-case?

Comment: if *process1* terminated - all threads in process terminated, included thread which own the mutex. as result mutex will be released and next waiters (say *process2* thread) became new owner - begin run. but if *process1* hung instead terminated and not direct release mutex before hang - of course another process will be infinite wait

Comment: Good point, I guess using mutex.time_lock() will address the hung scenario?

Comment: no, the hung scenario have no any solution. in sense you of course can wait for mutex not infinite but only some time, but what you will be do next, if wait finished by timeout ? only exit from process

Comment: Hmmmm... The lock would be released after the time-out period? So Process2 should be able to proceed?

Comment: of course you can wait on mutex only finite time, after which you can continue run. but mutex will be own by first hanged thread. so several processes in this case will be run in concurrent, which you want avoid. the mutex, if it owner hung, of course never will be released

Comment: but really correct code must not hung. so you not need take this to account. simply assume that process, which own mutex, release it explicit or terminate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally in C# is a procedural emulation of RAII.  As automatic storage variables have deterministic lifetime in C++ (scope wise), just do the unlock in a destructor.

The `std` library type is `unique_lock`; boost will have a similar one.  Have that lock the mutex, and unlock on destruction.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Just so I understand it correct, the purpose of unique_lock is to protect mutex against race condition due to multiple threads attempting to acquire the lock?

Comment: @bks no, it is an RAII type.  Unique means "intended to lock a mutex in non-shared mode".  Some mutexes (shared mutexes) have two locking methods.  If you do not know what  RAII google it and find some definitions or lessions.